# jquery mouseup not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://igt.bitballoon.com/

above is the website in reference, I am using some jquery functions and I have no idea why the mouseup one is not working.

**heres the jquery which is in  inside the head and yes i have a reference to jquery on there too**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#Clickables").mouseup(function() 
    {
        $(this).css({"background":'url("http://igt.bitballoon.com/images/clickani.png") no-repeat center', "background-size":"75% 75%"});
    });

    $("#Clickables").mouseout(function() 
    {
        $(this).css({"background":'url("http://igt.bitballoon.com/images/clickani.png") no-repeat center', "background-size":"75% 75%"});
    });

    $("#Clickables").mousedown(function()
    {
        $(this).css({"background":'url("http://igt.bitballoon.com/images/clickdown.png") no-repeat center', "background-size":"75% 75%"});
    });
});
```

**and heres the relevant html**

```
<div id="Clickables" class="blockclicker" onclick="GatherMoney();">
</div>
```

what i want to happen:when the image is clicked, i want it to change as long as the mouse is down and to change back to the original when the user lets go or leaves the area. the mousedown and mouseout events work fine. which doesnt make sense because when i made the mouseout event, i just copied and pasted the mouseup event and changed the event.
what the problem is: the mouseup event does not put back the original image with it properties, i believe it is the right image but the no-repeat center and size do not apply but they do for the mouseout function.

i am confused

Comment: This is bad practice. You should do classes in css and assign the appropriate class. Then you also could even forget about using javascript for this case using pseudo-classes.

Comment: Try removing the mouseout handler, I suspect the mouseup and mouseout are interfering with each other.

Comment: did my answer work for you

Comment: @MarkusZeller not sure how to do that.

Comment: @PatrickHund That didnt work for me either

Comment: @user3089009 no it did not

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this. I have tried [here](https://codepen.io/hasanB/pen/dRyZqe)

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#Clickables").mouseup(function() 
    {
        $(this).css({"background":'url("http://igt.bitballoon.com/images/clickani.png") no-repeat center', "background-size":"75% 75%"});
    });

    $("#Clickables").mouseout(function() 
    {
        $(this).css({"background":'url("http://igt.bitballoon.com/images/clickani.png") no-repeat center', "background-size":"75% 75%"});
    });

    $("#Clickables").mousedown(function()
    {
        $(this).css({"background":'url("http://igt.bitballoon.com/images/clickdown.png") no-repeat center', "background-size":"75% 75%"});
    });
});
```

```js
<div id="Clickables" class="blockclicker" style="height:200px; width:200px;" onclick="GatherMoney();">
  <button>click here</button>
</div>
```